# Getting Map API Key Errors on Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, api, dictionary, key, fusion

Having trouble with this page loading my google map correctly. I am trying to help a friend with this but I am stumped. The script to call in the API key is in there once but I am getting the following errors:

**You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.**

**Invalid Map Key**

Am I formatting this wrong?

```html
<?php  
$lat = 41.01413965527589;
$long = -102.53826150000003;
$pg_lat = get_field('pg_latitude');
$pg_long = get_field('pg_longitude');
if ( !is_null($pg_long) ) {
 $long = $pg_long;
}
if ( !is_null($pg_lat) ) {
 $lat = $pg_lat;
}

 $map_theme = get_field('pg_map_styles');

    $styles_file = get_template_directory() . '/assets/styles/map_styles.json';
    $map_styles = file_get_contents($styles_file);
?>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AlzaSyBYE1TZJEILsqvtODWyqh0okG7Ts1PNzv8&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
        function initialize() {
        var map;
        var layer_0;
        var layer_1;
        var styles = <?php echo $map_styles; ?>;

 var map_style = [];
 var user_style = styles['<?php echo $map_theme; ?>'];
 if (user_style && user_style['style'] != 'undefined') {
  map_style = user_style['style'];
 }
else {
 var default_style = styles['Light Dream'];
 if (default_style && default_style['style'] != 'undefined') {
  map_style = default_style['style'];
 }
}
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $long; ?>),
          zoom: 15,
styles: map_style
        });

        layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          clickable: false,
          query: {
            select: "col8",
            from: "13zAsmjWdE-uVeVPkr-1qqUQGfZFgPBnBwbNpsWEE"
          },
          map: map,
          styleId: 2,
          templateId: 2
        });
        layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: "col2",
            from: "1nhy-62Mdybjlipp3_kPrmZb_E4Z7fFjBVhNarqGk"
          },
          map: map,
          styleId: 2,
          templateId: 2
        });
      }
      window.onload = initialize;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function is "initialize" so put this function in url after api key and also re-create api. and then try it.